# UIViewController Margins

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2, margin, ios5

I have this a simple question: How do I resize a `UIViewController's` view from a custom `UINavigationController`, since it's not working to simply set it's frame.

I have tried to, in my `UIViewController`category, override setFrame of all `UIViews`, which didn't go well...

In a tableViewController I know I can set the `tableview's` `contentInset`, but that doesn't really help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add another view to your `UIViewController` 's view's subviews. Then change the frame of  this internal view is easy.